# Error when navigating with AppRoute Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, auto-route

I use `auto_route` and I have a problem with routing when I open app I get error (attached image below). I need it to check when opening application if the user is authorized and then push it to MainRoute.page.

**AppRouter**

```
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(
          page: AuthRoute.page,
          path: '/',
          initial: true,
          guards: [AuthGuard()],
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          page: MainRoute.page,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(path: 'dashboard', page: DashboardRoute.page),
            AutoRoute(path: 'crypto-list', page: CryptoListRoute.page),
            AutoRoute(path: 'settings', page: SettingsRoute.page),
          ],
        ),
        AutoRoute(page: CoinDetailsRoute.page, path: '/coin-details'),
      ];
}
```

**AutoRouteGuard**

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
    final AuthProvider appState = AuthProvider();

    if (appState.isLoggedIn) {
      resolver.next();
    } else {
      router.push(const AuthRoute());
    }
  }
}
```

**main**

```
return MaterialApp.router(
      theme: darkTheme,
      routerConfig: _appRouter.config(
        navigatorObservers: () => [
          TalkerRouteObserver(
            GetIt.I<Talker>(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
    );
```

**login screen**

```
void onPressedMethod(bool isRegister) {
    if (isRegister) {
      AutoRouter.of(context).push(
        const MainRoute(),
      );
    } else {
      AutoRouter.of(context).push(
        const MainRoute(),
      );
    }
  }
```

**error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that when user is not authenticated you are returning it back to the AuthRoute, which has Route Guard and the process repeat until you receive a StackOverflow Exception.

Please consider remove the guard on the AuthRoute

```
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(
          page: AuthRoute.page,
          path: '/',
          initial: true,
          //guards: [AuthGuard()], // <------ remove it
        ),
        AutoRoute(
          page: MainRoute.page,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(path: 'dashboard', page: DashboardRoute.page),
            AutoRoute(path: 'crypto-list', page: CryptoListRoute.page),
            AutoRoute(path: 'settings', page: SettingsRoute.page),
          ],
        ),
        AutoRoute(page: CoinDetailsRoute.page, path: '/coin-details'),
      ];
}
```

Comment: and on the LoginRoute page do I need to write something to receive and process onResult?

Comment: my point is that you don't need a guard on the AuthRoute, I'll update my Answer.

Comment: but if I remove the guards, I won’t be able to transfer the user using the authorization check